# Why is loop not doing its job?

Tags: java

So I have this code and for some reason the `String[]` it returns is always filled with a single "s". I want it to add an "s" to the end of every `String`, and if the value in the array is a null, to make it a single "s".

```
public static String[] fillArray( List<String> list ){
    String[] output = new String[list.size()];
    for(int a=0; a<output.length; a++){
        if( output[a]==null){
            output[a] = "s";
        }else{
            output[a]= list.get(a) + "s";
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: You're confusing the LIST and the OUTPUT.
Your check is if output[a] == null, which is always true. You'd want 'if( list.get(a) == null)

Comment: `new String[list.size()]` creates a `String[]` full of `null`. This makes your test for `output[a]==null` always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @KoosGadellaa Thanks! I just made a stupid mistake I suppose...

Comment: VTC as typographical error - unlikely to be of help to future users.

Comment: Maybe worth to mention that you can reach the same result by : String[] output  = new String[list .size()];
output  = list .toArray(output);

Comment: @CristianMeneses almost, since you need to replace `null` by `"s"`

Comment: Could also use a one-liner: `return list.stream().map(v -> v == null ? "s" : v + "s").toArray(String[]::new);`

Comment: @CristianMeneses `output = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);` would seem to be cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if( output[a]==null){`

needs to be

`if( list.get(a)==null){`

as the former will *always* be `null`, since that's what you're populating.

Answer (score 3):

`output[a]==null` is always null, it should be `list.get(a) == null`

Answer (score 2):

Output[a] is always null since you have not yet filled it.